# Textbox not getting updated in for loop

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a for loop in my WPF. The textbox does not get updated until the loop has finished.

My code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1500);
    // MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
    updateTextBox(i);
}
```

Update function:

```
private void updateTextBox(int i)
{
    // MessageBox.Show("reached here:" + i.ToString());
    txtExecLog.AppendText("\n" + i.ToString());
 }
```

If I uncomment the messagebox text, it updates one by one, otherwise it updates after 15 secs `(1.5*10)` the textbox with all the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're blocking the UI thread when you sleep. You mustn't do that - nothing can be processed on the UI thread while you're sleeping. If you want to take an action periodically (on the UI thread) use [`DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You are running your loop in the UI thread. When you call Thread.Sleep() the UI thread sleeps and therefore the textbox can't be updated before end of the UI thread blocking for loop.